# Can't find the problem here with topological sort

Tags: sorting, graph, graph-algorithm, topological-sort

I've just started a graph algorithm. There is a code of my topological sort algorithm with C++. It's a problem of UVA online judge.
my output doesn't match with the accepted output..
as if I give the input:->
8 25
8 6
5 2
7 4
7 1
8 6
6 1
7 1
6 2
8 6
8 6
5 7
6 2
8 4
1 3
7 1
1 3
6 7
1 3
6 4
2 3
5 2
6 3
8 4
4 3
5 6
0 0

My output is -> 5 8 6 2 7 4 1 3

but the accepted output is-> 8 5 6 7 4 2 1 3

as much as I know topological sort can have different acceptable outputs.
but I am still getting wrong answer.

[Link to the problem (Ordering tasks)](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=&problem=1246&mosmsg=Submission%20received%20with%20ID%2022842490)

Code:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void file(){
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
}

vector<int>graph[102],out;
int n,e,u,v,inDeg[102];

void Back(){
    memset(inDeg,0,sizeof inDeg);
    for(int i=0; i<102; i++)graph[i].clear();
    out.clear();
}

void init(int e){
    for(int i=0; i<e; i++){
        cin>>u>>v;
        graph[u].push_back(v);
        inDeg[v]++;
    }
}

void topoSort(){
    queue<int>q;
    int u;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        if(inDeg[i]==0)q.push(i);
    }
    while(!q.empty()){
        u=q.front();
        q.pop();
        out.push_back(u);
        int len=graph[u].size();
        for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
            int v=graph[u][i];
            if(inDeg[v]>0){
                inDeg[v]--;
                if(inDeg[v]==0)q.push(v);
            }
        }
    }
}

void print(){
    int len=out.size();
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        printf("%d ",out[i]);
    }printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    file();
    while(scanf("%d %d",&n,&e) && n!=0 && e!=0){
        init(e);
        topoSort();
        print();
        Back();
    }
return 0;
}
```

Should I keep a track of the visited node?

Comment: Please try providing more details regarding the problem you are facing. Is it wrong output? Is it some exception you are getting? Please add more details to you question.

Comment: well,  yes the output doesn't match with the debug
 as if I give input:->
8 25
8 6
5 2
7 4
7 1
8 6
6 1
7 1
6 2
8 6
8 6
5 7
6 2
8 4
1 3
7 1
1 3
6 7
1 3
6 4
2 3
5 2
6 3
8 4
4 3
5 6
0 0

i get the output->
5 8 6 2 7 4 1 3 
but the accepted output is -> 8 5 6 7 4 2 1 3

Comment: Please edit your question and put the details there. You are more likely to get the response as people don't go through the comments for more information on the question..